# Expect: How to get quotes to be sent

Tags: escaping, tcl, expect

In my below script i want to get the output from the spawn to be

```
ovirt-aaa-jdbc-tool user password-reset user--password-valid-to="2025-09-15 10:30:00Z"
```

but it ignores the quotes and gives me

```
ovirt-aaa-jdbc-tool user password-reset user--password-valid-to=2025-09-15 10:30:00Z
```

Ive tried several different ways, escaping the quotes etc but no joy. Code below

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set password [lindex $argv 0]
set username [lindex $argv 1]
set valid_to "2025-09-15 10:30:00Z"
set timeout -1


spawn ovirt-aaa-jdbc-tool user password-reset $username --password-valid-to=$valid_to
expect -re {(?n)^Password.*}
send "$password\n"
expect -re {(?n)^Reenter password.*}
send "$password\n"
expect -re {(?n)^user updated successfully.*}
send "history > his && echo hi\n"
expect -re {(?n)^#*}
send "whoami\n"
expect -re {(?n)^#*}
expect eof
```

Comment: expect is mostly tcl - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188395/tcl-set-special-characters-in-a-string - probably `set valid_to {"2025-09-15 10:30:00Z"}` would do what you want.

Comment: usually people don't code their app to require a param to be quoted. how do you run the command manually from a shell?

Comment: The quotes are needed for the space between date and time.  Double-escaping the space should work: `"2025-09-15\\ 10:30:00Z"`

Answer (score 1):

You are probably misinterpreting what you see. Expect does not split strings in variables on whitespace. The following simple shell script just prints each argument surrounded by ">...<".

```
cat >mytest <<\!
#!/bin/bash
for arg;do echo -n " >$arg<"; done; echo
!
chmod +x mytest
```

We run it from expect, using a variable which holds spaces:

```
expect -f - <<\!
set myvar "a   b"
spawn ./mytest v=$myvar
expect eof
!
```

This is the output:

```
spawn ./mytest v=a   b
 >v=a   b<
```

Although the echo of the spawn command printed by expect seems to suggest that there were 2 arguments to `mytest`, namely `v=a` and `b`, in fact the shell script only saw 1 argument, `v=a   b`.

This shows that the first part of your script is probably ok, and you should look elsewhere for the problem.
(Note, there is an example of the ovirt-aaa-jdbc-tool command [here](https://www.ovirt.org/develop/release-management/features/infra/aaa-jdbc.html) which matches what your are doing. It has `""` because it is being run from the shell, which will remove these quotes, and not split on whitespace.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also escape double quotes inside double quotes:

```
set valid_to "\"2025-09-15 10:30:00Z\""
```

Answer (score -1):

Enclosing the date in single quotes should work:

```
set valid_to "'2025-09-15 10:30:00Z'"
```

Comment: The OP did not mention that his app also supports single quotes.

Comment: It's `bash`.  The app is irrelevant.  The only difference between single and double quotes in `bash` is that the double quotes dereference variables.  He has no variables in the string.

Comment: The app knows nothing about shell quotes. It even does not care if it's invoked from shell or Expect. For your `set valid_to "'2025-09-15 10:30:00Z'"`, the single quotes would be passed to the app. For now it's very confusing what's the OP's real question.

Comment: The single quotes are not passed to the app.  The shell removes the quotes.  The quotes tell the shell to send that string to the app as one parameter instead of two. The string `2025-09-15 10:30:00Z`, without any quotes, single or double, is passed to the app as a single parameter whether single or double quotes are used.  The only difference between single and double quotes is that double quotes will dereference shell variables.  There are no shell variables in this example.